# stop meteor rerender every child template inside of each block when find query changes?

Tags: templates, meteor, each

i'm rendering a list of elements based on a collection on the meteor server.

the elements are rendered using an #each block which is populated from a helper method that returns a cursor which is the result of a find query. in order to sort the list based on some attribute of its data i run a new find with a different sort option.

this works fine and the list is rendered in the desired order. the problem is meteor is rerendering each element.

now i have two problems: 
1) the elements can contain an embedded video that is playing. this is reset when meteor rerenders the element
2) i want to have some css transitions animate the repositioning of the elements. since meteor rerenders every element in the dom, the css transitions don't work.

i was partially able to solve problem #1 using a constant block but problem #2 remains a mystery. i could do all the sorting and filtering client side without relying on meteor but that seems clumsy.

is there any way that meteor can just reposition the elements in the dom instead of removing and readding them?

in the documentation for renderList i found this (which makes it seem like meteor could at least theoretically do what i want):

*renderList is more efficient than using Meteor.render to render HTML for a list of documents. For example, if a new document is created in the database that matches the query, a new item will be rendered and inserted at the appropriate place in the DOM without re-rendering the other elements. Similarly, if a document changes position in a sorted query, the DOM nodes will simply be moved and not re-rendered.*

Comment: Did you try `preserve`? Don't forget to add an id if the selector points to more then one element.

Comment: the thing is I have some reactive elements inside the list items. if I add the whole element to preserve, none of the reactive elements would work anymore or am I mistaken?

I gave them all individual IDs

Comment: Reactive elements should work with `preserve`. It could help if you posted some code. Maybe this can help http://fogofcode.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/css-transitions-with-meteor/